# What does a &Number do?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix

I know that having an `&` at the end of a command makes it run in the background. I was wondering what does `&Number` mean? I was looking at a script that has some commands running with `&1` and some with `&2`.

Comment: I'd change the question to 

What does an &Number in the shell do?

Ampersand is used all over in Linux, the question is slightly ambiguous until you read details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be migrated to SuperUser, but the answer is that they refer to file descriptors. &1 is standard output, and &2 is standard error, so a program run like this:

```
./program 2>&1
```

Redirects descriptor 2 (standard error) to descriptor 1 (standard output)

A common use of this is to do something like this:

```
./program >file.txt 2>&1
```

Which redirects standard output into a file, and then standard error into standard output, so that you get both regular and error output captured in the file.

Comment: see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html section "3.6 Redirections" for more detail

Answer (score 1):

For Bourne type shells (bash etc.)

```
mycmd > /output/file 2>&1
```

merges the standard error output (file descriptor 2) with the standard output (file descriptor 1) and writes both of them into `/output/file`.

Answer (score 1):

The '&' indicates a file descriptor. &1 is stdout, and &2 is stderr.

If you haven't found a good site for learning shell scripting already, I recommend this one:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html

Answer (score 0):

`&1` is standard output (`STD_OUT`), `&2` is standard error stream (`STD_ERR`)